AttributeError: 'LlamaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'invoke'
I am trying to do some summarizations on chunks. Trying to use "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct". Code is as below
%%capture
from huggingface_hub import login

login(token="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")
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(load_in_4bit=True,
                                         llm_int4_enable_fp32_cpu_offload=True)


llm_llama_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct",
    torch_dtype=torch.float32,
    temperature =0,
    device_map='auto',
    quantization_config=quantization_config
)

llm_llama_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct")

then calling it
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template = """Write a concise summary of the following. The summary should be a list of bullet points. The summary cannot be more than 5 bullet points. The text is:
    {text}
    CONCISE SUMMARY:""",
    input_variables=["text"]
)

chunkSummaries = []

for split in splits:
  response = llm_llama_model.invoke(prompt.format(text=split.page_content))
  chunkSummaries.append(response.content)

I see AttributeError. Tried googling and the only answer i found was to use unsloth. Tried using it but had too many other errors. Any insights in resolving the attributeerror is greatly appreciated please
